# mdadm - root raid1 partition wont boot ( device not found )

Tags: centos, raid1

I had some soft raid issues, so i booted with SystemRescueCD and recreated / raid mirror ( md2 ) with "--create" option ( maybe that was a failure moment ). So on RescueCD boot all raid mirrors loads fine, they are active and mountable. But pure Centos 7 boot fails with "dracut-initqueue: Warning UUID=b1060ca9-809d-49fb-a072-e26b2342203a device does not exist".
But!
md0 mirror mounted successfully ( /boot/ ). Moreover - "mdadm --assemble --scan" command in dracut shell makes md2 up successfully. And i can mount and use all files on root filesystem.
But i cant understand why cant i boot automatically.

I've tried to rebuild initramfs ( like this https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=65655 ), nothing changed lol, still get "device does not exist" for root mirror md2.

/etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="consoleblank=0 fsck.repair=no crashkernel=auto rd.md.uuid=6e2d4d58-adaf-93f2-58c3-7506b3edd7a3 rd.md.uuid=75fbe2e5:02c33d4a:ed0366f0:0f2bb828 rd.md.uuid=ae486050-e006-16a3-528b-b912201d5819 selinux=0 rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

fstab

```
UUID=b1060ca9-809d-49fb-a072-e26b2342203a /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=d0eb6305-ef81-4e47-8f5c-38f81d4fab76 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=d6bd278b-0e71-4b9d-88e8-fc1dc783e4ee swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

mdadm --detail --scan

```
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 name=sysresccd:1 UUID=6e2d4d58:adaf93f2:58c37506:b3edd7a3
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 name=0 UUID=75fbe2e5:02c33d4a:ed0366f0:0f2bb828
ARRAY /dev/md/2 metadata=1.2 name=sysresccd:2 UUID=ae486050:e00616a3:528bb912:201d5819
```

blkid

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="6e2d4d58-adaf-93f2-58c3-7506b3edd7a3" UUID_SUB="003c3c43-b0c3-3f50-7d7c-ace743bf3e37" LABEL="sysresccd:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="0007332f-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="75fbe2e5-02c3-3d4a-ed03-66f00f2bb828" UUID_SUB="2ce014af-71e5-3f17-c335-757d03b7443a" LABEL="0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="0007332f-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="ae486050-e006-16a3-528b-b912201d5819" UUID_SUB="132ac662-3177-9221-4025-5a60b4dba2c2" LABEL="sysresccd:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="0007332f-03"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="6e2d4d58-adaf-93f2-58c3-7506b3edd7a3" UUID_SUB="498fc8f6-34d9-f286-c59e-2be87aa7dd9f" LABEL="sysresccd:1" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="000b2ac2-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="75fbe2e5-02c3-3d4a-ed03-66f00f2bb828" UUID_SUB="15f7666c-c538-1a1f-2c2f-828d3018cc19" LABEL="0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="000b2ac2-02"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="ae486050-e006-16a3-528b-b912201d5819" UUID_SUB="92c4a1dc-8445-7a56-a863-4384169ef355" LABEL="sysresccd:2" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="000b2ac2-03"
/dev/md0: UUID="d0eb6305-ef81-4e47-8f5c-38f81d4fab76" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/md2: UUID="b1060ca9-809d-49fb-a072-e26b2342203a" TYPE="xfs"
```

cat /proc/mdstat

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      935199744 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/7 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      261120 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      2094080 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

(md2 = /, md0 - /boot/, md1 - swap )

cat /etc/mdadm.conf

```
# cat /etc/mdadm.conf
# mdadm.conf written out by anaconda
MAILADDR root
AUTO +imsm +1.x -all
ARRAY /dev/md/0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=75fbe2e5:02c33d4a:ed0366f0:0f2bb828
ARRAY /dev/md/1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=6e2d4d58:adaf93f2:58c37506:b3edd7a3
ARRAY /dev/md/2 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=ae486050-e006-16a3-528b-b912201d5819
```

What should i look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem.

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=75fbe2e5:02c33d4a:ed0366f0:0f2bb828
ARRAY /dev/md/1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=6e2d4d58:adaf93f2:58c37506:b3edd7a3
ARRAY /dev/md/2 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=ae486050-e006-16a3-528b-b912201d5819
```

For some reason, the UUID entries had mixed uuid formatting ( : and - ). The same behavior is present on default/grub and grubcfg. After I fixed the md2 UUID format everywhere and generated a new grub.cfg and initramfs, everything worked like a charm.